# Locking cells with VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a spreadsheet with several sheets, which is protected except where I want people to make changes, and all is password protected.  I am trying to make a command button so others can view the data, but can't make changes to the cells.  Here is what I have (not working quite right).

```
Private Sub mdRead_Click()                                                    
    Dim ws As Worksheet 
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets 
        'To open wookbook as read only, while proctecting changes. 
        Worksheet.Unprotect = True 
        Worksheet.Range("C10:I23,L10:R23,C25:I36,L25:R36,C45:I58,L45:I58,C60:I71,L60:R71").Select 
        Selection.Locked = True  
    Next ws 
End Sub
```

Comment: OK so you select a number of cells. How does that help *'others can view the data'*?

Comment: The above code `Unprotect`s all sheets instead of protecting them. You might want to add `ws.Protect  yourPassword`.

Comment: Have you considered altering your [Worksheet.Protect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) to use the `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` option? With it, no action is restricted to a VBA process but hte user is still restricted.

Comment: Looks great!  thank you I will give it a try.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Having set the Locked property, you might want to protect the sheet again.

Comment: I did come up with this code that does most of what I want.           Private Sub CmdRead_Click()

Dim Sh As Variant
'for each sheet in workbook, protects unlocked cells
For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If Sh.Visible = True Then
    Sh.Select
    ActiveSheet.unprotect
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    Range("C10").Select
    Sh.Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        True
        
End If

Next Sh
Unload Me
MsgBox "Opened to read." & vbCrLf & "Not for Changes!"

End Sub